# Angular - reusing observable within a component?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

So, this is my use case: I get an observable from rest API, then by using `async` within the template I foreach the data. On click, I get the ID of particular user and then fill-in the form with the data of that user. To achieve the latter, I reuse the existing observable and filter the data, then subscribe to it. I was wondering if my approach is correct, since I believe that app is too slow when I  click "edit" for the form to get filled, so I'm guessing here that I create too many subscriptions or whatnot?

Also, for the sake of argument, I created two observables (`user` and `users`) and one (`user`) gets a "reference" to another (`users`), then it is displayed in the template with `async`, while I also subscribe to it and set it to a "regular" variable. Is this an issue? To display an observable with `async` and also subscribing to it?

Here's the code, since my question might be a bit confusing:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/find';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserService } from './service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div>
        {{user | async | json}}
        {{selected | json}}
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let u of users | async">
        {{u.first_name}} {{u.last_name}}
        <br />
        <img [src]="u.avatar" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <a (click)="edit(u.id)">Edit</a>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
            <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" />
            <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" />
        </form>
        <p>userForm value: {{ userForm.value | json}}</p>
        <p>validity: {{ userForm.valid }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: ['a { cursor: pointer; }']
})
export class App implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  users: Observable<any>;
  user: Observable<any>;
  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  name:string;
  userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: UserService) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      first_name: ['', {updateOn: 'blur', validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(10)]}],
      last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(20)]]
    })
  }

  edit(id) {
    this.user =  this.users.map(x => x.find(x => x.id === +id));

    this.user.takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(u => {
      console.log(u);
      this.selected = u;

      this.userForm.patchValue({
        first_name: u.first_name,
        last_name: u.last_name
      });

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('hello world');

    this.users = this.service.all();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  providers: [UserService],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here's the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/F0dheIdgoNNw53hNVjZm?p=preview

Comment: its seems correct enough, only thing is that getting users i would like to do it from the service rather than the component

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to use observables for this task. Although there is more straightforward method in the answer from Leon but for sake of learning about Observables let's do it :-)

You are subscribing to user observable in the template using async pipe but also in edit method. The subscription in edit method is never unsubscribed so there is a memory leak.

Also you redefine `this.user` observable each time you click on user and letting async pipe in template to resubscribe. This results in another memory leak since async pipe has no clue about the overriden observable which should be unsubscribed.

This is not really how you should compose your observable streams. First you should define the observable data transformation.

When I look on your application you have two sources of data/events:

1. users from service
2. clicks on edit button

Users are just observable from a service. Clicks should be really `Subject`. Because on edit you should emit the userId which was clicked (observable) and react on this click by displaying user detail (observer behaviour).

```
editClick: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>;
```

So let's define how `user` observable should look like (all this code in `ngOnInit`):

```
this.users = this.service.all().shareReplay();
this.user = this.editClick
    .switchMapTo(this.users, (userId, users) => ({ userId, users}))
    .map(x => x.users.find(user => user.id === +x.userId))
    .do((u) => {
        console.log(u);
        this.selected = u;

        this.userForm.patchValue({
            first_name: u.first_name,
            last_name: u.last_name
      });
   });
```

Here I define user observable based on editClick - thats where I will get id from later. Using `switchMapTo` I combine `users` observable and id from `editClick` into object which I use later to filter out clicked user.

Now how to trigger `editClick` in `onEdit` method? Just emit `userId` on each click like this:

```
edit(id) {
    this.editClick.next(id);
}
```

Notice how I define data stream in `ngOnInit`. Just once at beginning. No recreation or something. I have two observables to subscribe:

1. `users` to display users list
2. `user` to display detail - this one will emit each time I trigger `editClick`

Also there is only subscription in template therefore no memory leaks since `async` pipe will manage `unsubscribe` for you.

Comment: @uglycode did it help you to see what was wrong with your code? 

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify the edit method by passing the whole user instead of just the id.

```
<a (click)="edit(u)">Edit</a>

edit(user) {
  this.selected = user;

  this.userForm.patchValue({
    first_name: user.first_name,
    last_name: user.last_name
  });
}
```

As for calling `service.all()` multiple times will cause multiple subscriptions and multiple calls to the backend.

If you want to call it multiple times use the `.share()` rxjs operator.
That will create an wrapper subject around the observable which will return the same value each time it is called.

Comment: That's one of my questions, does the service.all() really get called twice? I don't believe so, since it's in the onInit

Comment: this.users is just a reference to the observable. You subscribe once with the async pipe in the template, and once in the edit method. You should be able to see chrome making double requests in the developer console. make sure you right click the developer console and check "Log XmlHttpRequests" to be able to see the requests going out.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to observe this in console... Also, is there an example of how to use share method?

Comment: I think I figured it, I used `shareReply` (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md), supposedly it's for stuff like this. Do you find this code correct? http://plnkr.co/edit/F0dheIdgoNNw53hNVjZm?p=preview